# What's your experience to deal with the offboarding account?

Tags: sql-server

I am thinking about doing the cleanup after the employee offboarding. Such as check across the multiple SQL instances and remove the offboarding account and the user on the database level.

Since it's across multiple SQL instances, I am considering using the dbatools PowerShell module. But not sure if it's a good way.

Anyone have a good experience to share with me?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Central Management Server (or Local Server Groups) is another option for multi server administration.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/administer-multiple-servers-using-central-management-servers?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you Sergey, I used CMS to manage my SQL inventory. But if we want to run the script against multiple SQ instances. We need to connect these SQL instances through CMS in SSMS first, and SSMS might crash once we have too many SQL instances to be connected at the same time.